# pagination using jquery not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I'm trying to create a simple pagination using jquery to no avail!

I need to use a class name `productHolde` which are the children of the `content` div to create the pagination but unfortunately I cannot get the class name and also, the pagination function is not working properly.

I have tried to use something like this:

```
$('#content').children(".productHolde").css('display', 'none');
```

in my code but this doesn't do anything!

I have created this jsfiddle to demonstrate the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/yc3mbeq2/1/

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,